# What language is this? Post from Wordpress saved into MySQL db (via a form)

Tags: wordpress

I'm not sure that this is the right place for this question, but I hope I can get some help.

I need to retrieve some records from a MySQL database. Said records contain info sent through a Wordpress form (as far as I know, without a plugin), and I have no idea what language it is. I need to be able to "translate" it for my non-tech co-workers, but I dunno what it is. At first I was told it might be JSON but none of the online JSON formatters recognize it as such.

```
s:483:"a:7:{s:5:"Name*";a:1:{i:0;s:6:"Tester";}s:7:"E-mail*";a:1:     {i:0;s:13:"test@test.com";}s:8:"Phone    number*";a:1:{i:0;s:8:"12345678";}s:9:"Comment";a:1:{i:0;s:4:"Test";}s:9:"_log_time";a:1:{i:0;i:1450794413;}s:12:"_log_form_id";s:4:"1941";s:10:"_log_mails";a:1:{s:14:"Webform";s:195:"<p>New message from <URL where the form is at></p>
<p>Name<br />
Tester</p>
<p>E-mail<br />
test@test.com</p>
<p>Phone number<br />
12345678</p>
<p>Comment<br />
Test</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
";}}";
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a language per se, this is an array serialized by `serialize()` function. If you want to get it back, call `unserialize()` and check its result.

Comment: To add / clarify @TomaszKowalczyk point (which is correct) - WP stores a lot of data in [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) form.  It's a "database-safe" way of storing information from an array, object, or other "non-string" form.  If you want to know what it says, you can put it into an [online unserialize tool](http://www.unserialize.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much @Tomasz Kowalczyk and @cale_b.
I have read about unserialize() and used the tool provided above but I'm not entirely sure how it works. From info like on my OP I need to extract the fields (name, e-mail, phone and comment) with its associated info and I'm unsure of how unserialize() can help with it, but thanks anyway.